# Upgraded to Phonegap 2.9.0 - deviceready not fired on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

After upgrading from Phonegap 2.5.0 to 2.9.0 I can no longer get the deviceready event to fire.

Things I have tried:

1. Adding the `cordova_plugins.json` file containing `{}`
2. Looking for `window.device` in a timer (never seems to be initialized) (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606870/phonegap-ondeviceready-wasnt-fired))
3. Removing the code from `cordova.js` that atrempts loading of `cordova_plugins.json` and replacing with `finishPluginLoading()`

Nothing seems to be working. I am pulling my hair out over this one. Please help while I still have some left!

---

Here is my code so far, however it has been through numerous iterations, so it contains some dead code showing other avenues I have tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function initializePhoneGap( success, failure ) {
        var timer = window.setInterval( function () {
            if ( window.device ) {
                window.clearInterval( timer );
                success();
            }
        }, 100 );
        window.setTimeout( function () { //failsafe
            if ( !window.device ) { //phonegap failed
                window.clearInterval( timer );
                failure();
            };
        }, 10000 ); //5 seconds
    }

    console.log( 'Waiting for launch...');
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile)/)) {
        //$(document).on("deviceready", didFinishLaunching, false);
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", didFinishLaunching, false);
        //initializePhoneGap( function(){ console.log('Phonegap initialized'); didFinishLaunching() }, function(){ console.log('Phonegap timed out'); didFinishLaunching() } );
    } else {
        console.log('Skipping phonegap initialization');
        didFinishLaunching();
    }

    function didFinishLaunching() {
        ....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ondeviceready should be the very first thing called, not inside of a .ready.

It should look something like this:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", deviceIsReady, false);

    function deviceIsReady() {
        /*This is where all of you initialization code should go. 
          With PhoneGap the deviceready should be the first thing*/
    }

</script>
```

Just stick with PhoneGap's deviceready instead of $(document).ready()

Comment: Wow. This actually makes perfect sense, and now I feel a little dense for not considering that the Phonegap event could be called before .ready!! Thanks!!